# JAAS automatic login without showing a login page/form

Tags: java, authentication, jboss, jaas

I have a java webapp that uses Spring MVC. the webapp is running on a jboss AS7.1 server that uses the JAAS login module with form-authentication. Logging in works smoothly when the user fills in his username and password on the form.

I would now like to create a java controller that "logs a user in" as if the user filled in the loginform.

```
public void logInProgrammatically(String username, string password)
{
    //???
}
```

When the method above finishes, any access to any secured page should be allowed because the user is considered logged in.

Can this be programmed by accessing Jboss's implementation of the loginModule, and setting some property?

Comment: May I ask what is the exact problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JAAS standard classes to achieve the authentication programatically. Lets say we are using our custom LoginModule implementation  (or any standard implementation), `com.sample.CustomLoginModule`. This login module is configured in jboss configuration XML.

Step 1: Define a security domain in JBoss. For other servers, the same information can be configured in JAAS config.

```
<security-domain name="customlogin" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="com.sample.CustomLoginModule" flag="required">
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

Step 2: Use custom login module to login user programatically.

```
public void logInProgrammatically(String username, string password){
    CallbackHandler handler = //use proper implementation to capture username and password arguments.
    LoginContext ctx = new LoginContext("customlogin", handler);
    ctx.login();
```

}

With this solution, you are not bound to specific Application server APIs. This code is portable across any application server with JAAS config changes.

For programatically authenticate using JAAS, see the tutorial from Oracle:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/tutorials/GeneralAcnOnly.html

Comment: This doesn't work because although I'm logged in in the context, the JBOSS container is not aware of this fact. As such, it will prevent access to secured pages and show the loginscreen. Why is this? What magical (request) property does jboss see/use that the login context does not set/use?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is what do you want: [Authenticating Users Programmatically](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gircj/index.html). It is part of Servlet API 3.0, not jboss login module.

Answer (score 0):

[WebAuthentication](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/WebAuthentication) from Jboss offers the functionality desired almost out of the box. The idea is that you can create your own servlet or custom class, like presented [here](https://roneiv.wordpress.com/2008/03/15/using-webauthentication-in-jboss/) that can call directly with a specified `user` and a `password`.

Ie. in your `logInProgrammatically` you can have something similar to what has been implemented in the `LoginHandler` presented [here](https://roneiv.wordpress.com/2008/03/15/using-webauthentication-in-jboss/):

```
public void logInProgrammatically(String username, string password)
{
    // ...
    WebAuthentication webA = new WebAuthentication();
    webA.login(username, password);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The Webauthentication class is not present in JBOSS7. It is available in older jboss versions. I'm not sure why it was removed. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @user1884155 Like mentioned in the comment on your other question. You can use`Servlet3AuthenticationFilter`, that is using `Servlet 3` login specs.